# Multiplication and modulo - Order of operations

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Simple question

I have $$a\cdot b\cdot c\;mod\;p$$

How do I interpret this? Do i read it as this $$(abc)\;mod\;p$$ or is it $$a\cdot b\cdot (c\;mod\;p)$$

Or do I completely misunderstand modular arithmetic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's $(a b c) \mod p$. In fact 
$$
x \mod p =(x)\mod p \text{ for any expression } x
$$

Comment: Oh brilliant explanation by generalising x as any expression

Answer (score -1):

You can see this as $a*b*c(mod p)$ or $a(mod\ p) *b(mod\ p)* c(mod\ p)$.